# Finding number of elements of a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have a dynamically allocated array called Deck, composed of Card objects which have two values, suit and number.

I need to find the number of cards from my deck array, which I declared as so:

```
deck = new Card[52];
```

I'm not sure how to determine the amount of elements in the deck if I change the amount of cards in the deck array.  Right now I have:

```
int size=0;
Card a;
while (a.getNumber() != '/0'){
    size++;
    a = deck[size];
}
```

where getNumber() is a function that pulls the number value of the card. However when I run the program is says "The program has stopped working"

Comment: It's `'\0'` (with backslash) and **not** `'/0'`.

Comment: It's not a matter of finding the size; it's a matter of recovering information that you threw away. And the answer is: don't throw it away. If you're going to need the size later, record it somewhere. That's what `std::vector` does.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in C++, or C. You need to create a structure:

```
struct Deck { int nCards; Card *cards; }
```

or, better way is use `std::vector<Card>`, which already does that for you. If you really don't want a structure, and for some reason do not want to use a vector, allocate a dummy Card pointer and set it to null to mark the end of array:

```
deck = new Card[52+1];
deck[52] = 0;
while (deck[i]) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I changed my code to what Pileborg says and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to store that number separate from the array, do something like a C string and use a sentinel value to indicate the end of the array or you could actually program in C++ and use a vector which can grow and shrink.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean when you say that the program says " The program has stopped working". I assume it's some sort of custom exception message.

However, I see a possibility of a buffer overflow (array index out of bounds exception) in your code.What if all the 52 slots in the array are occupied and then in the 52nd iteration,the value of the size variable turns 52 ,leading to an illegal index access in the deck array (it has been preallocated a set of 52 slots).

Also, this is certainly not a dynamically allocated array, because you are setting its size right at the initialization step.